# activerecord adding NULL as 'id' field?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I am creating a user via:

```
user = User.create attrs
```

Basically, it screws up by adding a 'id' field with value NULL which I am guessing evaluates as 0. So after the first user, I get an error that id must be unique. I can confirm that the attrs hash does not contain an 'id' field.

This is the generated SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`birthday`, `created_at`, `device_token`, `device_type`, `email`, `fb_id`, `first_name`, `gender`, `last_name`, `location`, `rstatus`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('1992-02-28 00:00:00', '2012-12-06 17:43:43', NULL, 'x86_64', 'adfas023@gmail.com', '12593646569', 'Test', 'male', 'Once', Test, 'Single', '2012-12-06 17:43:43')
```

What's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Your 'id' field should have been created as auto-incrementing by your migration.  Can you post the initial `create_table` migration for this table?

Comment: Ah wow you're right. I am not using migration, I setup the database table manually becuase I am on Sinatra and I dont have the rake tasks

Comment: So modify the id column to be auto-increment manually.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Do you want to post an answer so I can mark it as correct? I know it's stupid dumb mistake but it might be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `id` column should be auto-incrementing, and your migrations would normally ensure this is so.  If you can't/aren't using migrations, then fix it manually.